# Detecting when fancybox2 iframe content changes

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm just trying to detect people hacking around in an iframe by changing the source to another location.

I've seen references to .load function to detect when the content of an iframe changes but it's not working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe[id*=fancybox-iframe]').load(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
    console.log($('iframe[id*=fancybox-iframe]'));
});
```

The console.log in there is firing and showing it's detecting the iframe ok but I get no alert message when I manually change the source of the iframe with firebug, or when i click on links on the page within the iframe.

I'm using fancybox2.

I have also just tried this which works and alerts me:

```
onLoad="alert(this.contentWindow.location);"
```

But I don't know how to pass that to fancybox. If I edit the iframe element with firebug and add this line in and then click a link or edit the source I get an alert.

So I guess the main question here now would be how can I pass this to fancybox so it is added into the iframe when it's built?

:)